# How to use "apply" with a dataframe and avoid SettingWithCopyWarning?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am using the following function with a `DataFrame`:

```
df['error_code'] = df.apply(lambda row: replace_semi_colon(row), axis=1)
```

The embedded function is:

```
def replace_semi_colon(row):
    errrcd = str(row['error_code'])  
    semi_colon_pat = re.compile(r'.*;.*')

    if pd.notnull(errrcd):

      if semi_colon_pat.match(errrcd):
        mod_error_code = str(errrcd.replace(';',':'))
        return  mod_error_code

    return errrcd
```

But I am receiving the (in)famous

> SettingWithCopyWarning

I have read many posts but still do not know how to prevent it.

The strange thing is that I use other `apply` functions the same way but they do not throw the same error.

Can someone explain why I am getting this warning?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue with pandas version 0.23.4

Answer (score 1):

Before the `apply` there was another statement:

```
df = df.query('error_code != "BM" and eror_code != "PM"')
```

I modified that to:

```
df.loc[:] = df.query('error_code != "BM" and eror_code != "PM"')
```

That solved it.